# How to detect whether in Terminal Services session in VB6? 

Tags: vb6, remote-desktop, terminal-services

How can you detect whether the current session is a Terminal Services (Remote Desktop) session in a VB6 app?

Comment: You could try forcing the window to a restored (not maximised) state on load to see if that helps.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? `Form.WindowState` or some API call?

Comment: Yes, `Form.WindowState = vbNormal`.

Comment: @Deanna: You're right. It worked. I added that line to both Form.Load and Form.Activate and the behaviour has disappeared. Put it in an answer and I'll award it.

Comment: But it doesn't answer your stated question about terminal services :) Cody's answer does and so should be accepted IMO. If you'd asked "My app starts up funny in TS" then maybe I would have. If anyone reads into the details to see what your actual problem was, they'll also see my comment.

Comment: Ok, question changed. Sorry Cody! ;)

Comment: Yes, I could already tell the question was morphing into something else in the comment thread. I was hoping you'd take the hint and **post a new question** with your repro project, but apparently that didn't happen. Editing a question so drastically that it invalidates existing answers is considered bad practice around here; you should accept the answer you received and post a new question. I would have been happy to answer that new question, too. I don't get any rep for posting comments.

Comment: OK, question has been split into two (see other: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9713285/327528). I'm awarding Cody's answer here. If Deanna transfers her answer over to the second question I'll award it there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling the [`GetSystemMetrics` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724385.aspx) with the `SM_REMOTESESSION` flag will tell you whether the app is running inside a Terminal Services session.

To call that from VB 6, you need to declare it in a module like so:

```
Const SM_REMOTESESSION As Long = &H1000
Declare Function GetSystemMetrics Lib "user32" (ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
```

If you are running inside of a Terminal Services environment, the return value  will be non-zero.

...But you should really just fix your centering code, rather than trying to work around it with different behavior depending on whether you're running inside a Terminal Services session. That's just going to make more work for you and introduce more bugs. Unfortunately, I can't tell you what's wrong with the centering code you're using without *seeing* it.

Comment: @Craig: That's not what the answers to the linked question say. The problem is that your code to center the window is incorrect. It's making some assumptions that normally work fine, but fall apart when running under Terminal Services.

Comment: @Craig: Ah, I see what you're saying. You didn't write the form centering code, you're setting the property and letting VB handle it. So the bug is in the assumptions that VB makes about screen coordinates, not in something that you can fix. Yes, I understand what it was saying about the TS Config Tool, but that doesn't change the fact that the centering code is wrong, it just allows you to work around it if you don't have access to the source code.

Comment: Best would be to use `SPI_GETWORKAREA` to center your forms manually. VB ignores taskbar docking position and does not reload screen size on resolution change. Your bug is less common and not that irksome.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. As far as I understood, your form placed what you want where you wanted it (e.g. in the center of the screen). Your application works fine on a normal desktop, but it will be maximized in terminal environment. If so, I found a little trick. Put a timer on that form, make its `interval=1` and write in `timer1_timer` event

```
Me.WindowState = 0
'then put the movement code like this
formname.Top = (Screen.Height / 2) - (formname.Height / 2) -400 '(400 for form title bar)
formname.Left = (Screen.Width / 2) - (formname.Width / 2)
timer1.interval=0
timer1.enabled=false
```

That's it.
capanogli@hotmail.com

Comment: I solved the problem by adding `Form.WindowState = vbNormal` to both the Form Load and Activate events.